# How to pass parameters and variables from a file to jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to convert my jenkins pipeline to a shared library since it can be reusable on most of the application. As part of that i have created groovy file in vars folder and kept pipeline in jenkins file in github and able to call that in jenkins successfully

As part of improving this i want to pass params, variables, node labels through a file so that we should not touch jenkins pipeline and if we want to modify any vars, params, we have to do that in git repo itself

```
pipeline {
      agent
    {
        node
        {
            label 'jks_deployment'
        }
    }

    environment{
        ENV_CONFIG_ID = 'jenkins-prod'
        ENV_CONFIG_FILE = 'test.groovy'
        ENV_PLAYBOOK_NAME = 'test.tar.gz'
    }
    parameters {
        string (
                defaultValue: 'test.x86_64',
                description: 'Enter app version',
                name: 'app_version'
        )
        choice (
        choices: ['10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3'],
        description: 'Select a host to be delpoyed',
        name: 'host'
        )       
    }
        stages {
            stage("reading properties from properties file") {
    steps {
        // Use a script block to do custom scripting
        script {
            def props = readProperties file: 'extravars.properties' 
            env.var1 = props.var1
            env.var2 = props.var2
        }
        echo "The variable 1 value  is $var1"
        echo "The variable 2 value  is $var2"
    }
```

In above code,i used pipeline utility steps plugin and able to read variables from extravars.properties file. Is it same way we can do for jenkins parameters also? Or do we have any suitable method to take care of passing this parameters via a file from git repo?

Also is it possible to pass variable for node label also?

=====================================================================

Below are the improvements which i have made in this project

```
Used node label plugin to pass the node name as variable
```

Below is my vars/sayHello.groovy file content

```
def call(body) {
    // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
        agent 
        { 
            node
        {
            label "${pipelineParams.slaveName}"
        }
        }
        stages {
            stage("reading properties from properties file") {
    steps {
        // Use a script block to do custom scripting
        script {
          //  def props = readProperties file: 'extravars.properties'
         //   script {
  readProperties(file: 'extravars.properties').each {key, value -> env[key] = value }
//}
        //    env.var1 = props.var1
        //    env.var2 = props.var2
        }
        echo "The variable 1 value  is $var1"
        echo "The variable 2 value  is $var2"
    }
}
          stage ('stage2') {
            steps {
                sh "echo ${var1}"
                sh "echo ${var2}"
                sh "echo ${pipelineParams.appVersion}"
                sh "echo ${pipelineParams.hostIp}"
            }
    }
        }
      }
}
```

Below is my vars/params.groovy file

```
properties( [
    parameters([
        choice(choices: ['10.80.66.171','10.80.67.6','10.80.67.200'], description: 'Select a host to be delpoyed', name: 'host')
        ,string(defaultValue: 'fxxxxx.x86_64', description: 'Enter app version', name: 'app_version')
    ])
] )
```

Below is my jenkinsfile

```
def _hostIp = params.host
def _appVersion = params.app_version

sayHello {
  slaveName = 'master'
  hostIp = _hostIp
  appVersion = _appVersion
}
```

Now Is it till we can improve this?Any suggestions let me know.

Comment: I don't use declarative pipelines but it seems to me you should be able to read the properties in the groovy file before the pipeline declaration. Something like https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines.

Comment: From there I assume you can reference variables in the node label and the parameters default values in the pipeline declaration. Parameters are tricky though because the change only takes effect after the pipeline runs. So even if you can read the properties file this way you would have to run the pipeline twice to see any value change.

Comment: @Lionel Orellana - I have added what i have did so for after i have created this question.Please check and let me know is it still we can improve this or your suggestion's

Comment: You still have the problem that changes to the params groovy file are not reflected in the gui until after the pipeline runs. I imagine that's not what you want?

Comment: @Lionel Orellana yes that i don't want But do we have any option to rectify that?

Comment: Not the way you originally framed it. If you are reading the values from the properties file, why do you need the jenkins parameters at all? Just use the values read from the file.